# Is there an easy way to get a GType from a GStreamer element name?

Tags: gstreamer

I have a series of bins I want to iterate through, and within each bin I want to extract the first `queue` element.  Because the number of bins is arbitrary in this case, I won't know the name of the `queue` element, so I was hoping to use `gst_bin_get_by_interface()`, which takes a GType.

Is there a way I can go from an element name, like "queue", to a GType, without diving into the GStreamer header files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GstElementFactory class has this:

```
GstElementFactory* queue_factory = gst_element_factory_find("queue");
g_assert(G_IS_OBJECT(queue_factory));

GType queue_type = gst_element_factory_get_element_type(queue_factory);
```